# JAVA_HOME path not pointing to correct path

Tags: java, maven, java-home

I am using a VPN environment for code. Everything was working fine, but now I am not able to execute `maven` commands.

The error that I get is :

```
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

Now when I run the following : `%JAVA_HOME%` I get the following : `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin` instead of `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251`

And running : `java -XshowSettings:properties version`

```
Property settings:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
    file.encoding = Cp1252
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = \
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
    java.class.path = .
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\ext
        C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext
    java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre
    java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\LOCAL_~1.AHM\Temp\
    java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin
        C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin
        C:\WINDOWS\system32
        C:\WINDOWS
        C:\Python38\Scripts\
        C:\Python38\
        
        C:\Program Files\nodejs\
        C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\bin
        C:\WINDOWS\system32
        C:\WINDOWS
        C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
        C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
        C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
        C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\bin
        C:\gradle-6.5\bin
        %M2_HOME%\bin
        C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin
        C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin
        C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin
        C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
        C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Network Monitor 3\
        C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin
        C:\Users\arqam.ahmad\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

        .
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_251-b08
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_251
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.251-b08
    line.separator = \r \n
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Windows Server 2019
    os.version = 10.0
    path.separator = ;
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\resources.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\rt.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\jsse.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\jce.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\charsets.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\lib\jfr.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\classes
    sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\bin
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = amd64
    sun.desktop = windows
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level =
    sun.stderr.encoding = cp437
    sun.stdout.encoding = cp437
    user.script =
    user.timezone =
    user.variant =

java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

The Java_Home path seems to be an admin settings which I cannot change myself. So, is there anything which I can do for this problem from my side?

Comment: either get admin rights, or change the variable for your user

Comment: It's strange, though, how come %JAVA_HOME% refers to the Maven directory.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the

> Environment Variables

Hope the problem will be solved

New System Variable

In my cases, it looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can override the JAVA_HOME variable setting it in the Maven script file.

To do so, edit mvn.cmd and add the following line in the beginning of the file:

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add jdk physical path to environmental variable. It should resolve the problem